# How to remove <pad> and </s> on JupyterLab print output

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-lab, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm using JupyterLab notebook, installed via Anaconda, to run a machine learning application. If I run the application, JupyterLab automatically inserts <pad> and </s> tags at the beginning and end of each generated sentence.

Here is an example:

```py
import re
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
tweet_data = [
    'the coming days and weeks especially, ...platforms apply their standards in a mann',
    'With just 2 days to go, what does my timeline think about the #USElections2020',
    '..more data here'
]
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-base')
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-base')
text = " ".join(tweet_data)
TEXT_CLEANING_RE = "@\S+|https?:\S+|http?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+"
text = re.sub(TEXT_CLEANING_RE, ' ', str(text).lower()).strip()
Preprocessed_text = "summarize: "+text
tokens_input = tokenizer.encode(
    Preprocessed_text,
    return_tensors="pt",
    max_length=512,
    truncation=True)
summary_ids = model.generate(
    tokens_input,
    min_length=60,
    max_length=180,
    length_penalty=4.0)
summary = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0])
print(summary)
```

Here is the output:

```
<pad> srpoll: joebiden elections2020: joebiden of equality free.</s>
```

How do I ensure the <pad> and </s> are not on the print output? The application is user-facing, so the tags could impair their experience if they appear.

I've tried removing them as strings but I've not been successful.

Comment: what is the framework, what is the function? please provide the code, to make your question clear

Comment: I've edited the question with a code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.decode), you can skip special tokens by setting the flag `skip_special_tokens=True` (which is by default `False`). So, just change the `decode` line to :

```py
summary = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0],skip_special_tokens=True)
```

output:

```py
social media platforms should use their standards in mann with just 2 days to go. what does my timeline think about the uselections2020 more data here. the uselections2020 data is a mann with just 2 days to go. the uselections2020 data is a mann with just 2 days to go.
```